# fixed div position on scroll is not working in all conditions

Tags: jquery, css, position

hi to all i am making a div which will have fix position on scroll it will work if height is less but if height increase i can't scroll page any more 
i am not getting what is the problem i have made a jsfiddle for that have a look here

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sebtL/1/)

and code is

```
var div = $('.PropertyContainer');
    var start = $(div).offset().top;

    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function () {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        var height = $(div).height();
        $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');
        $(div).css('min-height', ((p) > start) ? '336px' : '70%');
        $('.FormWrapper').css('margin-left', ((p) > start) ? '181px' : '');
    });
```

please help me out it's being 2 days i am working on it but didn't get anything done

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you understand positions in CSS. You need to read up on the different types and how they behave ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)). Maybe if you can explain what you are trying to do then we can help you work out a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the height of the *PropertyContainer*. This one is the largest element on your page, thus defines the vertical scrollbar.

But when you start to scroll, you change his positioning to 'fixed'. At that point, the *PropertyContainer* height doesn't count anymore for the page's total height and the page shrinks vertically, causing the scrollbar to disappear shortly.

And then you get stuck in an infinite loop :

Scrollbar disappears > scrollamount=0 > position changes to static again > page gets higher > scrollbar reappears > ...

**Possible solution:**

When you make the *Formwrapper* higher so that *PropertyContainer* doesn't define the page height anymore, your script works.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/CdpeK/

Comment: thanks for the response but this thing is not fixed means PropertyContainer can be bigger than Formwrapper or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [fixed-position your elements using](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus) instead? That should work better and faster than JavaScript, although if you're targeting mobile devices, this option would be out of question (they do not yet support fixed positioning, at least older versions  of Android and iPhone don't).